# Как вывести информацию о событии в сообщении discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Не знаю, есть ли такая возможность, но нужно, чтобы пользователи с разными часовыми поясами при создании ивента видели время по их поясу, а не по МСК. Мысль была раздать роли с уже внесенными изменениями по часам. Далее надо по запросу пользователя предоставлять ему информацию, соответственно для его региона. Для этого нужно вытащить информацию из уже созданного События. Не понимаю, как обозначены эти пункты, чтобы получить к ним доступ.
Т.е. в слово setTitle попадает название ивента
Попытался найти информацию о

```
client.on('guildScheduledEventCreate', (guildScheduledEvent) => {

});
```

Но разобраться не смог. Есть ли какое-то обозначение этого, чтобы внести в переменную?

```
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
   if (message.author.bot) {
      return;
   }

   var event0 = moment().format('HH:mm');
   var event2 = moment(event0, 'HH:mm').add(2, 'h').format('HH:mm');
   if (message.content === "!событие") {
     if (message.member.roles.cache.has("1086316063205877248")) {
        const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
             .setTitle('название')
             .setDescription('описание')
             .setDate("дата")
        message.reply( { embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
        message.delete();
        }
    }
});
```